# select top newest records of different distinct column

Tags: sql, mysql

Example Data:

```
Date       City       Name
--------------------------
1/2/2011   New York   John
5/1/2011   Chicago    Matt
2/1/2011   Chicago    Mark
9/2/2011   New York   Johnny
3/1/2011   Boston     Phil
5/1/2011   Chicago    Martin
9/1/2011   Boston     Neil
2/2/2011   New York   Nicholas
1/2/2011   New York   Tom
3/2/2011   Chicago    Eric
5/1/2011   New York   Jack
12/1/2011  Chicago    Peter
11/2/2011  New York   Paul
9/2/2011   Boston     Steve
```

What I need is to take the 3 more recent records of each different city. I mean, the 3 newest records of New York, of Boston and Chicago.

I know I can do this in PHP, but imagine this table has thousands of records, it's not useful to take all records and take them to PHP :P

How is this possible in one MySQL query ?

Thank you !